# How to loop through items in pandas col and run and plot a scikit model?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, plot, scikit-learn

I got some interesting user data from races. I know when the respecitve athletes planed to finish a race and I know when they actaully finished (next to some more stuff). The goal is to find out when the athletes come in late. I want to run a support vector machine for each athlete and plot the decision boundaries.

Here is what I do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Create arbitrary dataset for example
df = pd.DataFrame({'User': np.random.random_integers(low=1, high=4, size=50),
                    'Planned_End': np.random.uniform(low=-5, high=5, size=50),
                   'Actual_End':  np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=50),
                   'Late':        np.random.random_integers(low=0,  high=2, size=50)}
)

# Fit Support Vector Machine Classifier
X = df[['Planned_End', 'Actual_End']]
y = df['Late']

clf = svm.SVC(decision_function_shape='ovo')

for i, y in df['User']:
    clf.fit(X, y)
    ax = plt.subplot()
    fig = plot_decision_regions(X=X, y=y, clf=clf, legend=2)
    plt.title(lab)
plt.show()
```

I get the following error: `TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable` - that is, I somehow can't loop through the column.

I guess it comes down to the numpy data format? How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User` Series contains `numpy.int64` objects so you can only use:

```
for y in df['User']:
```

And you don't use `i` anywhere.

As for the rest of the code, this produces some solution, please edit accordingly:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Create arbitrary dataset for example
df = pd.DataFrame({'User': np.random.random_integers(low=1, high=4, size=50),
                    'Planned_End': np.random.uniform(low=-5, high=5, size=50),
                   'Actual_End':  np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=50),
                   'Late':        np.random.random_integers(low=0,  high=2, size=50)}
)

# Fit Support Vector Machine Classifier
X = df[['Planned_End', 'Actual_End']].as_matrix()
y = df['Late']

clf = svm.SVC(decision_function_shape='ovo')


y = df['User'].values
clf.fit(X, y)
ax = plt.subplot()
fig = plot_decision_regions(X=X, y=y, clf=clf, legend=2)
plt.title('lab')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! I come from a slighty different tech stack and simply used the syntax I know and tried it out - clearly not successfuly. I think I did quite a mistake with using `y` and` `i` in the first place. I just want to cycle through the athletes - which indeed are `numpy.int64`  and run the clf for each athlete. I can't pull it off somehow. Any more tips?

Comment: thank you - that already helps quite a bit. However, I actually am trying to produce a plot for each athlete individually. That is, I am trying to loop through the `df['Athelte']` and run `clf()` and `plt.subplot()` for each athlete (four in this case). The dependend variable is still supposed to be `df['Late']` hence `y`.

Comment: I am thinking along the lines of something similar to `df.groupby('Athlete').apply(clf.fit(X, y))`

Comment: Thank you! I figure it out now!

Answer (score 2):

try iteritems()

```
for i, y in df['User'].iteritems():
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't quite get it so far. I tried your method and `for i in df['Responsible User'].itterows():` Both returns `'Series' object has no attribute 'itterows'`

Comment: sorry, my mistake, try iteritems()

Comment: Ok thanks! I think I am getting there. I guess I need to convert the dataframe to a `np.array` first? I am getting the error `y must be a 1D NumPy array`.